# how to obtain eigenvalues of a bosonic state?

Tags: bosons

Suppose have a bosonic state as follow:

$a \left| 0nm \right> \left< 0nm \right|+b \left| 0nm \right> \left< 1(n+1)(m+1) \right|+c \left| 1(n+1)(m+1)\right> \left< 0nm \right|+d \left| 1(n+1)(m+1)\right> \left< 1(n+1)(m+1)\right| $

where n and m are 0,1,2,...

also 0 and 1 are basis of a qubit.

its not possible to represent the density matrix of this state by basis 1 , 2 , ....

we have to use this basis instead to represent the state

$\left| 0nm\right>,\left| 0(n+1)m\right>,\left| 0(n+1)(m+1)\right>,\left| 0n(m+1)\right>
\left| 1nm\right>,\left| 1(n+1)m\right>,\left|  1(n+1)(m+1)\right>,\left| 1n(m+1)\right>$

if we do that can we calculate eigenvalues of the matrix like a normal finite matrix?

if not then how we can do that?

Comment: Can $n$ and $m$ go to infinity? I.e., is the basis infinite dimensional? If so that makes things a little bit harder

Comment: Infinite dimensional operators don't always have eigenvalues: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1486876/889261 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1486876/889261 and others probably discuss this. For bosonic operators, consider that there is no right eigenstate of the creation operator $a^\dagger$ but there is a right eigenstate of the annihilation operator $a$.

Comment: Yes the basis are infinite dimensional

Comment: In the case of infinite-dimensional operators, specialized tools are required to analyze the properties of the density matrix (e.g. spectral decomposition, functional calculus).